# How to reset or deselect highlighted item on selectfield in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Good Day!

I have a selectfield which i need to reset or deselect highlighted item on it after selecting an item.

Below is my code:

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
id: 'slActionRequired',
placeHolder: 'SELECT ACTION REQUIRED',
name: 'ActionRequired',
label: 'Action Required<span style="color:red">*</span>',
autoSelect: false,
usePicker: false,
options: [
{ text: 'YES', value: 'YES' },
{ text: 'NO', value: 'NO' }
],
```

I tried below code but nothing works:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#slActionRequired')[0].reset()
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#slActionRequired')[0].setValue('');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do here - do you want the select field changed so it doesn't read "YES" or "NO" or do you want to remove one of those from the options field? Off the top of my head - I would be using itemIds rather than ids as this would allow multiple instances. If you want to blank it, you could put an option in: { text: '-', value: '' }  - your setValue('') call will at least do something then

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Ext.field.Select class and modify the item selection in the showPicker function.

```
Ext.define('Ux.field.Select', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Select'
    xtype: 'myselectfield',


    showPicker: function() {
      ...

     // Modify the last line of the showPicker function
     // Remove the item selection when the select field is displayed.
     //list.select(record, null, true);


    }
}
```